# USB Overdrive how to use a modifier key to change the macro executed

Tags: keyboard, automator, mouse

On my Mac I use USB Overdrive to assign the macros <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> to switch tabs quickly with my mouse's side buttons. I wanted to know if it was possible to make it so that when I am holding down a certain key e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press these side buttons I can have it execute a different macro than when <kbd>Shift</kbd> isn't held down?

Basically, I want to be able to use the side buttons to either switch between tabs or go forward/backward depending on if I'm holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: I know ControllerMate allows you to specifier modifier keys to differentiate different button presses.  Isn’t there a setting for selecting a modifier to a mouse button when assigning a macro?

Answer (score 0):

I know with [LinearMouse](https://github.com/linearmouse/linearmouse) (freeware), there's a setting for it to use the universal back and forward, which should accomplish the same thing. From its settings:

"Enable universal back and forward:

Convert the back and forward side buttons to swiping gestures to allow universal back and forward functionality."